# Electricity to ground

Tags: capacitor, ground, esd, shock

I was working on a games console and accidently got shocked by a capacitor.
I was wearing a ESD strap that was connected to the back of my pc which is connected to a powerboard and to a grounded power outlet.

My question is with that shock, could I have damaged my pc any other games consoles that are connected to the same powerboard?

Comment: What is a 'poweboard' ?
Was the console plugged into the AC mains when you were working on it ?

Comment: the console was unplugged, not sure what brand the powerboard is but it is surge protected and grounded.

Comment: You didn't answer the question--what is a powerboard? That's not a word I've ever heard before.

Comment: Sorry I misread the first part. A powerboard is the same as a power rail.

Comment: Why isn't your wrist strap connected to earth via a 1 Mohm resistor? I thought that was standard procedure?

Comment: What's a "power rail"? Do you mean a mains distribution socket strip or plugboard? The term power rail would usually mean a single conductor inside an electrical panel.

Comment: Yeah a plugboard, In Australia we usually call them powerboards but I have seen the advertised as power rails, couldn't think of anything else to call them sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It is doubtful that you damaged other devices plugged into the same power rail, but for you to be shocked by a capacitor must have required a high voltage on it which is not typical inside a games console unless it is in its power supply. That can be dangerous as the power supply capacitors may remain charged to a high voltage even if the console is unplugged.

Comment: Thanks for your help, yes it was psu capacitor. 

I touched it by complete accident, now I'm more concerned about my other systems. 

So the shock would have just followed the path to ground and ignored everything else?

Comment: It could have gone to whatever else you were touching at the time.  If you triggered the shock with something metallic, it is possible that the connections on the PSU capacitor may be slightly damaged or pitted, but that is unlikely to make it fail.

Comment: The cap itself still works, I actually can't remember how I touched it (was a few weeks ago). Either I was using tweezers to pick up a drop screw and accidently brushed the cap or used my fingers to pick it up and touched the cap. Or I accidently brushed the top of the cap with my fingers.

Comment: Yes, however, it really depends upon the intensity of the shock. I faced a similar incident, but my other components mounted on same board were completely safe.

Comment: I was wearing an esd strap so that is the main worry about where the electricity went?

Comment: It can be verified only by testing other consoles but to my knowledge, it must have followed the ground path.

Comment: Thanks for your help. One final question, not all of the consoles connected to the powerboard have a ground prong on their plugs, does that matter? Would the still have followed safely to ground without damaging things?